# Using javascript replace() inside jquery attr()

Tags: jquery

I want to use jquery to select a specific anchor tag on my page, and apply the replace() method to it (I am trying to replace &#039 with %27, I am having apostrophe issues when submitting my form...) and I'm not sure exactly how to do this. I started to write this:

```
    $(".view-subscription-admin tbody td.views-field-nothing a").attr("href
```

and then realized that I wasn't sure how to use this with the replace function. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".view-subscription-admin tbody td.views-field-nothing a")
              .attr("href", function(i, oldHref) {
                   return oldHref.replace('&#039', '%27');
               });
```

***[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr)*** method support a callback function and within that argument you can do your replace code and return that `href`.

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that its not working for me. I know that I have the selector correct because I just tried attr("href", "hello") and it worked. I tried changing the items to replace (to something simpler) and it still did nothing...

Comment: @user1015214 Please share the link to fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the suggested answer didn't work for me, but someone else gave me a different suggestion and this one worked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".view-subscription-admin tbody td.views-field-nothing a").each(function(i) {
            var oldHref= $(this).attr('href');
            var newHref = oldHref.replace('&#039;', '%27');
            $(this).attr('href',newHref);
  });
});
```